# How to replace string in parsing html with php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I get a string like this: `Last Draw - 11 10 12`
I need to replace `Last Draw - 11 10 12` with simple `11.10.12`. 
So I need to remove the "Last Draw" phrase and put dots between the numbers.

I tried several times and I got either wrong result or error.

```
$result = preg_replace('LAST DRAW', "", $result );
```

Last time I tried this code: `$result = preg_replace('LAST DRAW', "", $result );` with no result.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: your code example has no occurence of either the string or any preg_replace/str_replace? What is it good for? consider editing your question and focussing on what you want to do with your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **`str_replace()`**

```
$string = "Last Draw - 11 10 12";
$var1 = str_replace("Last Draw - ", "", $string);
$var2 = str_replace(" ", ".", $var1);

echo $var2;
```

Result will give you 11.10.12

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that date could be any not just 11 10 1

Comment: @user3467607 What would be possible dates? Could you edit your question and define what date formats can be expected?

Comment: @Andresch Serj The date format: 07 07 07 (or any other value)
Need: 07.07.07 or 07.01.01 etc.

Comment: @user3467607 I do not mean what numbers will be expected, i asked for the format. Will you have dates like `3 12 2014` or `23 4 99` or even `7 7 '89`? Will there possibly be different seperators than spaces? Like `12-12-1999` or `13/4/04`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `preg_replace` incorrectly (invalid pattern).

Do this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/Last Draw - /', '', $result);
```

or simply use string replace:

```
$result = 'Last Draw - 11 10 12';
echo str_replace('Last Draw - ', '', $result); // outputs: 11 10 12
```

Comment: Thanks! But the date could be any not just 11 10 12

Comment: so? I am only replacing `Last Draw -` with nothing, leaving what ever else comes after it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$regexSearch = '/Last Draw - ([0-9]{1,2}) ([0-9]{1,2}) ([0-9]{1,4})/'; 
$regexReplace = '$1.$2.$3';
$str = 'Last Draw - 11 10 12
Last Draw - 2 12 2014
Last Draw - 24 3 99
'; 

echo preg_replace($regexSearch, $regexReplace, $str);
```

you can see it running [here](http://ideone.com/RFg8Pe).

It basically searches for any dates that look like 1 to two numbers for the first and second value and 1 to 4 for the third value. You could use the following code to have any numbers for the three terms:

```
/Last Draw - ([0-9]{1,}) ([0-9]{1,}) ([0-9]{1,})/
```

You can use [regex101](http://regex101.com/) to learn to write such regex code and test it directly on their website.